# Is there a way, on Windows 10, to get a list of the most opened folders (given a certain period of time)?

Tags: windows, powershell, file, scripting

It could be used to auto pin folders to Quick access in File Explorers, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been digging around in the inner workings of the file system and registry for years and I don't think there is anything that does exactly what you want.  But, there is a feature that you might try to make use of.

Files have a Last Accessed timestamp, I know this from my experience with the command prompt, so I did a test to see what PowerShell can give us:

```
Get-ChildItem | Format-List -Property *
```

Looking at the list of properties I found that both directories and files have these properties:

```
CreationTime      : 7/30/2020 8:00:25 PM
CreationTimeUtc   : 7/31/2020 1:00:25 AM
LastAccessTime    : 7/30/2020 8:02:07 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 7/31/2020 1:02:07 AM
LastWriteTime     : 7/30/2020 8:02:07 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 7/31/2020 1:02:07 AM
```

With a little bit of experimenting, you might be able to make good use of LastAccessTime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pin frquently used folders to Quick access just open File Explorer Options and in the General tab check the "Show frequently used folders in Quick access" box.